# Why does Eclipse make you give a variable a value after declaring?

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

Eclipse will give you an error if you don't give a variable a value after you declare it.
Example:

```java
double num;
//Error: local variable might not have been initialized
double num2 = 0.0;
//No error
```

This will cause eclipse to give you the error: `local variable might not have been initialized` when you attempt to use the variable.
. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: We can't help you with this part of the code. Please give us more details.

Comment: added more context and clarity

Comment: That code doesn't give that error - you should only be getting the error if you try and use `num` - show us code that actually produces the error.

Comment: The short answer is that the Java Language Specificiation says that this is an error which must be reported - see [JLS§4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

Answer (score 1):

Check settings in Eclipse to see if you've enabled stricter handling of warnings. There's a checkbox in Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings that says: *"Treat above errors like fatal compile errors"*. I suspect that is checked for you. Also, take a look through the various settings in the same "Errors/Warnings" section to see which ones you might want to change.

What you're observing is within Eclipse itself. That setting makes it harder to proceed with possible programming mistakes, since warnings can be (and often are) ignored by a human.

By default, that setting is off when creating a new project in Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0). Your code – `double num;` – generates a warning only.